# Why does the Scala 2.11 compiler rename my private method?

Tags: scala

I was quite surprised when I compiled the following code to observe that the compiled method name differed:

```
package com.toto
class A {
    def foo1: Any => Int = ???
    def foo2: Seq[Any] => Seq[Int] = _.map(foo1)
}
class B {
    private def foo1: Any => Int = ???
    private def foo2: Seq[Any] => Seq[Int] = _.map(foo1)
}
```

Then I finally have for methods and their relative names (depending on the scala version also):

```
scala 2.12.4:
A => (...)
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.A.foo1() -> getName: foo1
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.A.foo2() -> getName: foo2
B => (...)
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.B.foo1() -> getName: foo1
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.B.foo2() -> getName: foo2

scala 2.11.8:
A => (...)
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.A.foo1() -> getName: foo1
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.A.foo2() -> getName: foo2
B => (...)
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.B.com$toto$B$$foo1() -> getName: com$toto$B$$foo1
     public scala.Function1 com.toto.B.foo2() -> getName: foo2
```

I searched on the scala documentation what could lead to this particular name for the class `B` compiled in `scala-2.11.8` but could not find anything relevant.

Can someone explain to me or redirect to a useful resource please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SethTisue: my bad I thought implementations would not matter but they actually do, and so does the scala version. So I updated my post: I'm using `scala-2.11.8` and in order for it to occur I do need to have the implementation of `foo2` given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**short answer**

`foo1` must be public in bytecode because it is referenced from another class representing a lambda, and thus must be renamed so the original name remains free for use in subclasses.

**longer answer**

As you've already discovered, the details of the code matter here. In particular, it's important that you reference `foo1` from the body of a lambda.

In Scala 2.12, most lambdas can be represented without creating a separate class at compile time, but in Scala 2.11, we don't have JDK 8's lambda support to make use of, so scalac must emit an additional, separate class to represent the lambda.

As a result, `foo1` which is `private` in the source code, must be declared `public` in the bytecode, otherwise it wouldn't be accessible from the class representing the lambda.

And because `foo1` is now `public` in the bytecode, it must be given a different name than just `foo1`, because it must be permissible for a subclass of `B` to have its own member named `foo1`, having nothing to do with how it is defined, privately, in the superclass.

In other words, it needs to still be possible for me to write, later, perhaps in some other compilation unit:

```
class C extends B { def foo1 = ... }
```

without the public `foo1` in `C` having anything to do with the private `foo1` in `B.` Thus, the renaming of `B`'s `foo1` is forced, since we can't give both methods the same name, and we'd much rather mangle a private name than mangle a public one.

**meta-answer**

As for your meta question of where you could have learned this, I don't know.

It would be lovely if there were a document at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/index.html documenting everything special or unexpected you might see in scalac-generated bytecode. (Reasons to care: reflection, Java interop, Java serialization, performance...?)

But, no such document exists. So to have figured this out yourself, you probably would have needed some combination of:

- experimentation to narrow down the conditions under which renaming happens
- reasoning from first principles about why renaming might be necessary
- digging in the source code for the compiler

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very clear and I really appreciate the effort you took in explaining in such details. I guess the documentation cannot mention everything and it's already a big piece of information ;-) Thanks again.